# Simulink numerical evaluation to prevent overflow

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have this function

```
f(a,b) = { 
            a*a/b   if a < b,
            b       if a >= b 
         }
```

defined for values of a and b between 0 and 1 inclusive.

The function is continuous at all valid values of a and b in this range. (Really! try it yourself!) But I'm not sure how to evaluate it in Simulink. The problem is that I can't figure out how to restate it in a way that I could evaluate both "forks" of the function and take the min or max (e.g. `min(a*a,b*b)/b`) without having a divide-by-zero error at `b=0`, and I'd like to avoid getting into things like conditionally-executed subsystems.

Does anyone know how I might go about doing this?

Comment: if a and b are constrained to [0,1], then it is impossible to divide to by 0 as this only happens if a < b --> a < 0 which doesn't belong to [0,1]

Comment: You're not understanding my question. The problem in Simulink is that unless you execute conditional subsystems or matlab functions (e.g. MikeT's) that are slow, you cannot execute a branch and decide whether or not to execute code. The function I gave has a branch and I'm trying to see if there's a way to evaluate it with a branchless technique. The min/max/abs blocks are branchless (from outside the block). The function `min(a*a,b*b)/b` is a branchless version but it causes a divide-by-zero error at b=0 even though the function itself has no discontinuities at b=0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some strange constraints. Since you insist on evaluating both forks and taking the min of the two, the only solution is to not divide by zero but by a small enough number to avoid an error (eps for instance).

[image]

or with if action blocks:
[image]

Comment: +1, but I could do without the implications that what I'm asking for is weird. If there's a more straightforward but still performant way of calculating this (e.g. an easy way to use conditional subsystems?), I'd like to know that.

Comment: I can't speak to the performance of if action blocks, but it's not that hard to implement one.

Comment: ok, thanks. For some reason I was thinking you had to create a clock signal to decide when to execute each block (which I guess is what the if/else block does)

Comment: I think what he was asking was do you really need to have both branches computed beforehand, and then take the min?  Or can you just check the condition first, and then compute the branch that you need?  If you can do that, it should be fairly easy to do it using an If block and action subsystems.

Comment: Maybe a different question will help, what in particular do you find difficult about conditionally executed subsystems?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest approach would be to use a [MATLAB function block](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html).  You could code it up like this,

```
function retVal = myfunc(a, b)
   if (a < b)
     retVal = a*a/b;
   else
     retVal = b;
   end
end
```

This will create a block with 2 inputs and one output.  I'm not sure how you are ensuring that a,b \in [0,1], but this will work as long as that restriction is satisfied.