# How to eliminate data 0 in matlab simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm a foreigner. I'm not good at english.

I have question about matlab simulink. I have a lot of data that include 0 but i don't need 0 because i would like to square.

For Example 17/0  zero can not use.

What is block diagram to eliminate 0 from my data?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to protect your Simulink model from divide by zero errors. You may want to have a look at [Simulink numerical evaluation to prevent overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196654/simulink-numerical-evaluation-to-prevent-overflow) and also this [technical solution](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-F5WMK3/index.html) from MathWorks.